# Telerik Grid ASP.NET MVC4 Grid Binary Operator Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik Grid in an ASP.NET MVC4 view that is throwing a very odd error.  I have this code working in other areas of the application without issue...  With the client template code removed for the IsActive property the error still occurs.  The error goes away when I remove the `.Filterable(...)` call.

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types
>   'System.Boolean' and 'System.Object'.

#### VIEW

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataKeys(keys =>
      {
          keys.Add(c => c.Id);
      })
    .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden();
          columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(c => c.IsActive).Width(100).Title("Active?")
             .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" })
             .ClientTemplate("<center><input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' 
                name='IsActive' <#= IsActive? checked='checked' : '' #> /></center>");
      })
    .Filterable(f => f.Filters(fi => fi.Add(fis => fis.IsActive)))
)
```

#### MODEL

```
public class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {
        IsActive = true;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(5)]
    [MaxLength(300)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Is it the `<#= IsActive? checked='checked' : '' #>` causing the error?

Comment: What is it that is causing the error? Try removing and adding stuff until the error doesn't occur... once you lock down what is actually causing the issue, we can go from there.

Comment: Just added a bit of info at the top of the Q.  Essentially it is the `Filterable(...)` call that throws the error.

Comment: @Charlino - thank you for taking the time to try and assist!

Comment: Haven't seen <center> in ages...

Comment: LOL - old habits die reallllll hard :)  No worries though CSS has magically appeared now that this bug was fixed.

Comment: @RSolberg - np, I'm glad my assistance got you to where you needed to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already found out the problem is with your `Filterable`

So you always need to specify an "operator" when adding the a default filter in your case I think you need the `IsEqualTo(true)`

```
.Filterable(f => f.Filters(fi => fi.Add(fis => fis.IsActive).IsEqualTo(true)))
```

Comment: And the idiot of the year award goes to YOURS TRULY!  Thanks man.  Much appreciated.  Although I duplicated the code from somewhere else, it just functioned differently and didn't throw the error.  I can confirm it wasn't working there though either...

Again, much appreciated.